# How to monitor files added or deleted from USB connected to mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb

Through objective c coding. I want to get notified whenever a file is added to USB connected to my mac. I want to track all I/O operations done on it.Till now i am able to get notified whenever a USB is connected and Removed using

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(volumesChanged:) name:NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification object: nil];
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(volumesRemoved:) name:NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification object:nil];
```

Similarly want to know whenever any operations are done on it. Any help is appreciable. Thanks in advance

Comment: With these notifiers, i am able to get notified whenever any USB is connected. So when i get notified i am seeing what all files are there in it by giving ls command. And i am monitoring it for every 2 min. But it is little bit tough to check all files every time. So i am looking for an alternate to get only files added or deleted from USB. @RobertKenny

Answer (score 1):

You can use FSEvents for monitoring file system changes. This is the documentation  - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/